# Materialize: translateY transformations set in % are jumpy in Safari

Tags: css, forms, safari, css-transforms, materialize

In Materialize CSS, I find that `translateY` transformations set in `%` are jumpy in Safari. The same thing happens in Safari for iOS and MacOS.

The jumpyness disappears when the transformation is set in `px` or `em`/`rem` instead of `%`.

Please see this Fiddle to better understand the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/rz0zk5u6/224/

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is related to a bug in Safari with `translateY` and transformations set in `%`. See the Fiddle for an example with a fixed `px`-fix that corrects the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/rz0zk5u6/224/